# Can't style some components with java Synth?

Tags: java

I can't seem to style MenuItem's or their MOUSE_OVER state

here is my XML
`

```
<!--ROOT-->
<style id="genericStyle">
    <font name="sans-serif" size="14"/>
    <state>
        <color value="#FFFFFF" type="FOREGROUND"/>
    </state>
</style>
<bind style="genericStyle" type="region" key=".*"/>

<!--BUTTON-->
<style id="buttonStyle">
    <property key="Button.textShiftOffset" type="integer" value="1"/>
    <insets top="5" left="10" right="10" bottom="5"/>
    <opaque value="TRUE"/>
    <state>
        <color value="#FFFFFF" type="TEXT_FOREGROUND"/>
        <color value="#FF5252" type="BACKGROUND"/>
    </state>
    <state value="MOUSE_OVER">
        <color value="#FFFFFF" type="TEXT_FOREGROUND"/>
        <color value="#ff5757" type="BACKGROUND"/>
    </state>
</style>
<bind style="buttonStyle" type="region" key="Button"/>

<!--MENUBAR-->
<style id="menuBarStyle">
    <insets top="3" left="7" right="7" bottom="3"/>
    <opaque value="TRUE"/>
    <state>
        <color value="#3F51B5" type="BACKGROUND"/>
    </state>
</style>
<bind style="menuBarStyle" type="region" key="MenuBar"/>

<!--MENU-->
<style id="menuStyle">
    <insets top="2" left="5" right="5" bottom="2"/>
    <opaque value="TRUE"/>
    <state>
        <color value="#FFFFFF" type="TEXT_FOREGROUND"/>
        <color value="#3F51B5" type="BACKGROUND"/>
    </state>
    <state value="MOUSE_OVER">
        <color value="#FFFFFF" type="TEXT_FOREGROUND"/>
        <color value="#C5CAE9" type="BACKGROUND"/>
    </state>
</style>
<bind style="menuStyle" type="region" key="Menu"/>

<!--MENUITEM-->
<style id="menuItemStyle">
    <opaque value="TRUE"/>
    <state>
        <color value="#FFFFFF" type="TEXT_FOREGROUND"/>
        <color value="#3F51B5" type="BACKGROUND"/>
    </state>
    <state value="MOUSE_OVER">
        <color value="#FFFFFF" type="TEXT_FOREGROUND"/>
        <color value="#C5CAE9" type="BACKGROUND"/>
    </state>
</style>
<bind style="menuItemStyle" type="region" key="MenuItem"/>
```

`

My UI: https://gyazo.com/9846976fa7aed3c8469b780d0f85b7bd
The button is working as intended so I'm confused. I am new to Synth and XML so I could be easily be doing something wrong but I can't figure out why.

Comment: What are your expected output?  It seems to work okay for me, but maybe I'm missing something

Comment: When you hover menu items the color should change to a lighter blue, also MenuItems don't seem to respond to any adjustments made.

Comment: At the moment, I can only get "selected" to work.  `Menu` and `MenuBar` may not respond to `MOUSE_OVER` states...

Comment: Strange... Any idea as to why?

Comment: Without digging into the code, it's impossible to be sure that the statement is true, it's also possible that the designers choose not to included those states for there own reasons

Comment: Oh my... I'm stupid that awkward moment when you create a JMenu instead of a JMenuItem :/